# How to load and display an animated png

Tags: c++, c, animation, mfc, png

I have an animated png that I want to load in my MFC project to show it animated. I need this because it's a loading animation, and I would love to know how to do it. Would love if you can tell me how this works for png files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1427/Add-GIF-animation-to-your-MFC-and-ATL-projects-wit

Comment: I already knew about this, but this is for gifs,I know that i can transform the png to a gif but there must be a way to do it directly with pngs. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hey Cosmin, as far as i know apng is not supported. You can also try to use this sample code from here http://www.ucancode.net/CPP_Library_Control_Tool/Load-Display-png-image-file-mfc-sample-code.htm and load all the images into an array and cycle trough it while updating the window until the loading is finished (but iam not sure if that will result in "window blinks/flashes")

Comment: thanks,I searched hard and really didn't get anything, was hoping since c++ is a very versatile language,I guess I would just have to split the png into every state and cycle through it. Thank you for your fast responds.

Comment: No problem you have the problem now not in 2 weeks ;-)!